# How to parse an XML String into Java Object?

Tags: java, xml, web-services, xml-parsing

I have an XML String that I get as response from a web service. I want to parse it and convert it to a Java object. Please help me solve it. I have tried using various libraries but failed. All giving some exception.

**XML** String :

```
<LOGINRESPONSE xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"     
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Message="Login Successful"   
    Token="SFTT67FGHUU" DataFormat="CSV" Header="true" Suffix="true"  
    xmlns="http://ws.eoddata.com/Data" />
```

The code that I used is:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(
    "http://<webservice URL>/Login?Username=<username>&Password=<password>");
ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
String response = httpclient.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
System.out.println(response);
try (ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(response.getBytes())) {
    Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(bais);
    System.out.println(doc);
} catch (Exception exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

But doc is coming as `null`. I want to extract the token from the xml string

Comment: "some exception"? Which library/-ies? What exception? One of first things to note is that due to unusual capitalization of elements, most data-binding libraries (like JAXB, or Jackson's XML module) will require overrides (annotations usually) to map XML elements to Java properties.

Comment: On trying to use
Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse("XML String")
I get this exception:
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LOGINRESPONSE xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Message="Login Successful" Token="021D29TDDPEG" DataFormat="CSV" Header="true" Suffix="true" xmlns="http://ws.eoddata.com/Data" />

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to wrap the `String` in a `ByteArrayInputStream` and pass it to a `DocumentBuilder`, for example...

```
String text = "<LOGINRESPONSE xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" Message=\"Login Successful\" Token=\"SFTT67FGHUU\" DataFormat=\"CSV\" Header=\"true\" Suffix=\"true\" xmlns=\"http://ws.eoddata.com/Data\" />";
try (ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(text.getBytes())) {
    Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(bais);
} catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Updated...**

To extract an attribute, you might use something like...

```
NamedNodeMap atts = doc.getDocumentElement().getAttributes();
Node node = atts.getNamedItem("Message");
System.out.println("Message = " + node.getTextContent());
```

which prints...

```
Message = Login Successful
```

Comment: When I try this, I get doc as null.

Comment: Really, I get `[#document: null]` (using `System.out.println(doc);`) which says the `Document` was created successfully...

Comment: How do I extract token from the XML String

Comment: That makes a nice change...I mean, of course it did ;)